# Entitymanager throwing NullPointerException

Tags: jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, entitymanager

Am developing a JavaEE application using Netbeans.The Entity Manager is getting a null value in the application. The em is not getting injected.
Still am getting a nullPointerException as em is getting a null value in createNamedQuery.
Could anyone please let me know what am I missing.

JSP page- index.jsp:

```
<%@page import="managed.userBean" %>
 <jsp:useBean id="bean" class="managed.userBean" scope="session" />
.....
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="<jsp:scriptlet> bean.validate();</jsp:scriptlet>" />
```

userBean.java

```
package managed;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import session.UserFacade;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped


public class userBean implements Serializable {

private String uid, password,role,fname,lname;
private String response="" ;
@EJB
UserFacade userFacade;
....
public String validate() {
    System.out.println("in validate going to user facade:  " + uid + password);
    response = userFacade.validateUser(uid,password);
 .....
}
```

UserFacade.java

```
package session;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless

public class UserFacade extends AbstractFacade<User> {
@PersistenceContext (unitName = "ExamSysPU")
public EntityManager em;
String role;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    System.out.println("check if em is open");
    return em;
}

public UserFacade() {
    super(User.class);
}


    public String validateUser(String uid, String password) {
     ...
              List results = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByUid").setParameter("uid", uid).getResultList();
   ....
}
```

Persistence.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="ExamSysPU" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
     <jta-data-source>test</jta-data-source>
      <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
      <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

Thanks,
Shilpa

Comment: Make sure you have defined your persistence unit correctly and that the unit name is consistent between your code and your 'persistence.xml', or post it here.

Comment: Have updated with the 'persistence.xml' file.I have checked the name and it is consistent. Have been stuck here from past 1 week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused because you created `UserBean` manually using `<jsp:useBean>` instead of using the one created and managed by JSF for you (and thus having all the necessary dependencies auto-injected for you). Essentially, if you're *manually* creating and managing beans, then you should also *manually* be creating, managing and injecting its dependencies.

Stop reading those decade-old JSP 1.x tutorials. They are not applicable anymore these Java EE 6 days and would only confuse you as to the proper approach these days. JSP has been succeeded by Facelets (XHTML). Work through some JSF2/Facelets tutorials. Basically, your concrete problem can be solved by replacing the JSP file by a Facelets file with at least the following content:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.validate}" />
</h:form>
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) - contains a JSF2/Facelets Hello World kickoff example and several links to sane JSF2 tutorials

Comment: It does work with xhtml.The problem that I faced with using XHTML was I couldn't add a new namespace. Got an error saying namespace not found in library. I updated my web.xml, created new dtd.. Still couldnt resolve it. 
So switched to JSP where I could use taglib.
Would you also happen to know how to add a new namespace in XHTML.

Comment: You can't use a JSP taglib in Facelets. You need a Facelets taglib instead. This is however a completely different problem which should be asked in a separate question if you still can't figure it out. You can find some kickoff examples starting at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269

Comment: Was not using JSP taglibs, I was adding in the                          xmlns:c="http://www.ckeditor.com">   .. Will post a new question for that.

Comment: It look like that the problem is bigger than expected (they are **actually** JSP taglibs, a 3rd party one even). Well, I'll see your new question.